# ggplot change heatmap for xvalues exactlys

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, heatmap, lines

In my image I get a heatmap and I want to put specific data, which would be the years: 2014,2015,2016, with different colors, then I want to change the name of the ylab as I do, and finally how I add Title. 
Thank you in advance.

The code I used was this:

```
ggplot(TLM, aes (Month, Temp)) + geom_line(aes(group = Year, color = Year))
```

[image]

My database is distributed as well:

[image]

Comment: What is your question? Also, please include a reproducible example.

Comment: Claudia - did the answer below help you?

Answer (score 0):

With your chart `g <- ggplot(TLM, aes (Month, Temp)) + geom_line(aes(group = Year, color = Year))`

**To add a title:**

```
g <- g + ggtitle("My heatmap title")
```

you can also use `labs(title = "my title")`. This [link shows](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Titles_(ggplot2)/) if you need to do tricks like use \n to split long titles over two lines.

Note the [new ggplot2](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/labs.html) has features to add captions and so on.

**Change my ylabel**

Use ylab to do this. Let us assume you want to say Temperature (Celsius) not Temp

```
 g <- g + ylab("Temperature (Celsius)")
```

**Change wording on top of legend**

Lets say you wanted to change Ano to Year for an English publication

```
g <- g + labs(color = "Year")
```

**EXAMPLE CODE IN FULL**

So putting this all together on a subset of your data, it would look like this:

[image: example plot of temp]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

mydata <- data.table(Ano = c("2015", "2015", "2016", "2016"),
                     Mes = c("Enero", "Febrero", "Enero", "Febrero"),
                     Temp = c(18.17, 18.63, 20.66, 21.1))

#> mydata
#    Ano     Mes  Temp
#1: 2015   Enero 18.17
#2: 2015 Febrero 18.63
#3: 2016   Enero 20.66
#4: 2016 Febrero 21.10

#ggplot(TLM, aes (Month, Temp)) + geom_line(aes(group = Year, color = Year))
g <- ggplot(mydata, aes (Mes, Temp)) + geom_line(aes(group = Ano, color = Ano))

# splitting it for illustrative purposes
#  you can do this all in one step ggplot + ggtitle + ylab etc.
# title
g <- g + ggtitle("My heatmap title") 

# ylab
g <- g + ylab("Temperature (Celsius)")

# legend
g <- g + labs(color = "Year")

#Plot chart
print(g)
```